# What is the keyboard shortcut to select everything between quotes in VSCode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, base64, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a quick way to select `data:image/png;base64,...` between matching quotes in VSCode.

[image]

I assigned `editor.action.selectToBracket` keybindings to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> as keyboard shortcut. This will
select everything between `php` tags.

[image]

---

Another attempt is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>. This will select a whole single line.

[image]

Is it possible to accomplish this task in VSCode without relying on any extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve the issue, I used the following steps: I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> to select the text from the current cursor position to the end of the line, and then I pressed the <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> key to reduce the selection size.

[image]